# Product Image (Not Found) Via Web Service

Tags: php, web-services, api, upload, prestashop

I have a problem, when I upload a product with Web Service its created no problem, but its image is not found. Below i post the code of upload of products and images and some photos.

```
       <?php
    require_once 'PSWebServiceLibrary.php';
    define('PS_SHOP_PATH', 'localhost/tienda');

    //Descomenta y cambia producto por categorie y anade categoria
    try{
        $webService = new PrestaShopWebService( PS_SHOP_PATH ,'KEY_DE_WEBSERVICE',false); $xml = $webService -> get(array('url' => PS_SHOP_PATH.'/api/products?schema=blank'));//blank $resources = $xml -> children() -> children();

    if ($_POST['enviar']){        //'enviar is a button'
        echo "Has pulsado enviar";
        //Values of form HTML
        $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
        $precio = $_POST['precio'];
        $stock = $_POST['stock'];
        $short_desc = $_POST['short_desc'];


        $id_created_product = $resources->id;
        echo $resources->id;
        $resources->active = 1;
        $resources->id_category_default = 3;
        $resources->name->language[0] = $nombre;
        $resources->link_rewrite->language[0] = 'mi_producto';
        $resources->description->language[0][0] = $short_desc;
        $resources->price = floatval($precio);

        $resources->id_manufacturer;
        $resources->id_supplier;
        $resources->new;
        $resources->cache_default_attribute;
        $resources->id_default_image = 1;
        $resources->id_default_combination;
        $resources->id_tax_rules_group;
        $resources->position_in_category;
        $resources->type = "virtual";
        $resources->id_shop_default;
        $resources->reference = "ref_product";
        $resources->supplier_reference;
        $resources->location;
        $resources->width;
        $resources->height;
        $resources->depth;
        $resources->weight;
        $resources->quantity_discount;
        $resources->ean13;
        $resources->upc;
        $resources->cache_is_pack;
        $resources->cache_has_attachments;
        $resources->is_virtual;
        $resources->on_sale;
        $resources->online_only;
        $resources->ecotax;
        $resources->minimal_quantity;
        $resources->wholesale_price;
        $resources->unity;
        $resources->unit_price_ratio;
        $resources->additional_shipping_cost;
        $resources->customizable;
        $resources->text_fields;
        $resources->uploadable_files;
        $resources->active = 1;
        //$resource->redirect_type;
        //$resource->id_product_redirected;
        $resources->available_for_order = 1;
        $resources->available_date;
        $resources->condition;
        $resources->show_price = 1;
        $resources->indexed;
        $resources->visibility;
        $resources->advanced_stock_management;
        $resources->date_add;
        $resources->date_upd;
        $opt = array('resource' => 'products');
        $opt['postXml'] = $xml -> asXML();
        $xml = $webService -> add($opt);



       //Upload of product image

        $url = 'localhost/tienda/api/images/products/id_del _producto';   //Or any number id product of the shop

        $file_name = realpath('./m.jpg');  //     Trial image

        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD,'KEY_DE_WEBSERVICE'.":");

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('image' => '@'.$file_name.';type=image/jpeg'));

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        if(curl_exec($ch) === false){
            echo 'Error : '.curl_error($ch).'<br>';
            }
        else {
            echo 'Added Product';
            }
        curl_close($ch);    

    } 



}
  catch (Exception $ex) {
     echo 'Se ha producido un error: <br/>'. $ex->getMessage(); 
}

  if(!defined('_PS_VERSION_'))
     exit;

  class Prueba_2 extends Module{

     public function __construct(){
        $this->name = 'prueba_2';
        $this->tab = 'front_office_features';
        $this->version = '1.0';
        $this->author = 'myname';
        $this->ps_versions_compliancy = array('min' => '1.5', 'max' =>'1.6');

        parent::__construct();

        $this->displayName = $this->l('Trial 2');
        $this->description = $this->l('This is a description');
        $this->confirmUnistall = $this->l('Are you sure to want to uninstall?');
    }

    public function install() {
        if(parent::install()==false)
            return false;
        return true;
    }


}


?>
```

[IMG]http://i67.tinypic.com/b67w47.jpg[/IMG]

[IMG]http://i67.tinypic.com/6ydu2u.jpg[/IMG]

Please I need help, its very important for me

Comment: Noticed you have un-closed brackets in the code posted (try and if). And all those $resources->indexed; without assigning anything are pointless.

Comment: Sorry, I have failed to copy. Post edited.

Answer (score 1):

If you are adding image using url then first you need to store that image in local folder and then need to add that image's local path to $file_name.
Also instead of using @ in curl_setopt used the curlfile it would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that this code doesn't work with any product.

```
 //Upload of product image

 $url = 'localhost/tienda/api/images/products/id_any_product';   
 //Or any number id product of the shop

 $file_name = realpath('./m.jpg'); // Trial image
 $ch = curl_init();

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD,'KEY_DE_WEBSERVICE'.":");
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 
             array('image' => '@'.$file_name.';type=image/jpeg'));
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

 if(curl_exec($ch) === false){
    echo 'Error : '.curl_error($ch).'<br>';
  } else {
     echo 'Added Product';
  }

curl_close($ch);
```

I want to upload a image for any product created but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the same code as you, actually it is the code you find in [Prestashop documentation](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Chapter+9+-+Image+management) and it works. 
The only difference, I presume, is in the type of the image that in your code appears in the path. The documentation does not do any use of the type.